# How to remove transition effect when data changed in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await

On Vue.js 2.x, I have a component which is fetching data from server like below.

```
<template>
...
<a href="..." v-if="data.status !== 'blind'">Link</a>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
...
data: {
  return() {
    data: {}
  }
};
...
async created() {
  const loadedData = await this.$axios.get(`server-url`);
  this.data = loadedData.data;
}
</script>
```

So, this works fine with not rendering the anchor tag when `data.status` is 'blind', but It takes a little time to disappear even though using `await`.

Is there any way to render `v-if` after axios data is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note, you have an error in your `if` condition. It should be:

```
v-if="data.status !== 'blind'"
```

Anyway, in my opinion the best way to handle ajax calls is to use a flag. Something like this:

```
<template>
...
<a href="..." v-if="!loading && data.status !== 'blind'">Link</a>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
...
data: {
  return() {
    loading: false,
    data: {}
  }
};
...
async created() {
  this.loading = true;
  const loadedData = await this.$axios.get(`server-url`);
  this.loading = false;
  this.data = loadedData.data;
}
</script>
```

Comment: whats the difference between your v-if and his v-if? because you said he has an error in it